# How can I convert .mp4 files and .srt file to images based on subtitle's timeline?

Tags: video, kindle

I have .mp4 file and .srt file. I need to convert them to images including subtitle. The problem here is that I only want to capture images that have subtitle. I will use these images to read video lecture by my Kindle. Anyone who knows which tools can adapt my work please tells me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two tools described here that you can use to convert videos with subtitles into suitable form for Kindle: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=231289